# Symfony 2 Service How To Feed My Own Data Into My Service?

Tags: php, symfony

Ok, I have set up a few services in the pass but not many, so my knowledge about them are some what limited.

I have set it up like so,

```
upload:
    class: MyBundle\Classes\Upload
    arguments: [@doctrine.orm.entity_manager, %FormData]
```

So I trying to set up my own class to upload my file data. I am doing this has there are a number of controllers that will need to upload the data. I have also tried using, `@FormData` and `$FormData`, but still not passing my form data into my service?

Form data is being set as follows:

```
// getting just the file non mapped, form element
$FormData = $form->get('file')->getData();
```

This is how I called it in my Controller,

```
$this->get('upload', $FormData)
```

However `FormData` always seems to just dump the variable name and not pass the data into my class.

So my `Upload` class is set up like this:

```
class Upload
{
    private $Data;

    public function __construct(EntityManager $em, $Data) {
        $this->em = $em;
        $this->data = $Data; <-*Note 1
    }

    public function UploadFile() {
        // ...do something and save path/data into File Entity...
    }
}
```

And yes I am loading the 'EntityManager' namespace into my class...

So why is my `$this->data` not contain my form data passed to it?

Note 1: This is what I was doing a `var_dump()` on and it was just displaying `$FormData` or `@FormData`.

All help most welcome....

Thanks.

---

### UPDATE

What I am thinking is set it up as a normal class like,

```
$UploadData = new Upload($Data, $em);
```

And pass in my data and then the $em?

Is that the best why to set this up?

Thanks

Comment: It looks like you are trying to pass formData to get and have it be injected into the constructor?  Does not work that way.  get only takes one argument.  Maybe something like: $upload = $this->get('upload')->setFormData($formData);  There is also a cookbook article on uploading files that might be worth taking a look at.

Comment: @Cerad - Dam, I was thinking that I could not do that way. I think it be so cool if I could - I should have also said I am using Symfony 2.7 :) - I give your 'setFormData' a go and let you know. Thanks!

Comment: @Cerad - Sorry mate, that did not work, Attempted to call an undefined method named "setFormData" - I have an idea, I post as an update

Comment: What Cerad means is you would have to create your own `setFormData()` function and then call that...or in your case it would make more sense to just pass the data you need to the function in your service that uses that form data.  Those services you are creating are instantiated before any of your code gets ran, so you can't pass data to their constructors later in the way that you want.

Comment: Yep.  What @JasonRoman said.  As far as your edit goes, it will work but it means you need to have access to $em and to remember to inject it.  Just play around some more.  Eventually,the use of services will become clearer.

Comment: Thanks guys! I am just don't have a clue about where to set about setting up my own 'setFormData()'. I am guesting (please correct me, as I think I wrong) that this would have to be set in the Entity, along with all my other getters/setters?

Comment: I think I set it up as a normal class and just inject my '$em' - its not the best but should work for now. And when I go though the code, I look at making it a service. If someone could post an example of how to do the setter and where I would put it? that would be grate... thanks guys!

Comment: You can use a service - just continue to do some reading...it can be a bit confusing, but your `setFormData()` function would be in your service, not the entity.  I'll try to post an example for you.

Comment: @JasonRoman - Ok that makes more sense. Thanks for your help. Right Now I have it working as a class. But I would like to know how to set it up as a service... Thanks for your help and Thanks to Cerad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were really close.  The idea behind the service you created is that it is reusable - so you wouldn't want to directly inject a single form's data in the service's constructor.  The only thing you want to inject is any other services you might need - in this case, the [Doctrine entity manager](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/ORM/EntityManager.php).

That service is created before any of your controller code is executed, so you would have no way of passing your form data to the constructor anyway.  Symfony uses [dependency injection](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection/index.html) to do all of the heavy lifting for you, passing in the Doctrine entity manager so you don't have to manually do that, like you were trying.  So your service definition is going to be simplified:

```
upload:
    class: MyBundle\Classes\Upload
    arguments: ["@doctrine.orm.entity_manager"]
```

The defiinition of your service is simplified as well:

```
use Doctrine\Orm\EntityManager;

class Upload
{
    private $em;

    public function __construct(EntityManager $em) {
        $this->em = $em;
    }
}
```

You now have the option of creating a setter for your form data, but it's probably better to just pass it to an `uploadFile()` function in your service, like so:

```
class Upload
{
    public function uploadFile($formData)
    {
        // do something with the form data here
    }
}
```

Then you can simply do the following in your controller:

```
$this->container->get('upload')->uploadFile($form->get('file')->getData());
```

Comment: Not only a very good example but so so simple. Thank you so so much.... I come from use CakePHP for years and each time I drive a little deeper into Symfony, its just seems that little bit more powerful.

Comment: You're welcome!  Yeah definitely take some time to go through the documentation - services seem daunting at first but they're really no different than regular classes, other than Symfony will auto-inject other services for you based on your configuration.

Comment: I would agree with you about the documentation, however the Symfony docs, seem to just be aimed a little at someone who already knows what to do. They are good, just some of there wording is sometimes like, what :( - I think they could give some more examples....

Comment: Years ago when I learned Symfony and hadn't really used any frameworks before, I found that it was best to start from the beginning of their documentation and not just read it, but actually go through each example and do it.  As in, create a webserver, install Symfony, create a controller, a service, integrate a database, a Twig template, etc.  I found it the best way to learn the framework.